# dropdownlist asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Осваиваю ASP.NET MVC. В качестве практического задания решил переписать приложение, написанное на WebForms.

Есть View, в котором из таблицы выводятся объекты с указанными свойствами:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@using Domain.Entities
@model IEnumerable<Weapon>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Weapon";
}

@foreach (Weapon weapon in Model)
{
    <div>
        <h3>@weapon.Name - @weapon.BasePAttack</h3>
    </div>
    <hr />
}
```

В WebForms нужно было присвоить `combobox` ссылку на коллекцию `comboBoxOfWeapon.DataSource = sortListOfWeapon`

Как поместить выводимую информацию в `dropdownlist`(аналог `combobox`) и в чем принципиальная разница между `dropdownlistfor`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Применение `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.PropertyName, Model.ListOfItems)` создаст разметку вида:

```
<select id="PropertyName" name="PropertyName">
   <option value="1">Значение 1</option>
   <option value="2">Значение 2</option>
</select>
```

Атрибуты `id` и `name` соответствуют названию поля в модели.

Здесь `x.PropertyName` - свойство модели, в котором предполагается хранить выбранное значение. В него будет записано `value` при биндинге модели (если вы планируете его использовать).

В `Model.ListOfItems` хранится список `SelectListItem`, на основании которых генерируются теги `option`

Аналогичная функция без for `@Html.DropDownList("name", Model.OrderList)` попросит вас указать `name` самому. Этот атрибут будет использоваться для получения значения из запроса: `var value = Request.Form["name"];`

Comment: У меня, при создании лямбда-выражения, на переменной х можно вызвать только встроенные методы и свойства. Что я упустил?

Comment: У меня в VS 2015 подсказки обновляются только через некоторое время после изменения модели. Также, попробуйте сделать Build. Иногда бывает глюк, который лечится закрытием и открытием файла.

Comment: Видимо проблема в том, что я пока не создал модель(папка пуста). У меня обращение  к базе происходит через интерфейс

Comment: Суммирую Ваш ответ и инфу от толкового индуса с ютуба, удалось решить проблему.